# Excel Ranking with Duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking to sort a column of data in Excel.  I need to sort a bunch of other columns based on this sort so I would like to give a rank to each member of my column based on its value that I can use to sort everything else.

Initially I used RANK() but this does not account for duplicate values, they will appear the same and I need unique values for my purposes.  Some hunting around brought me to this equation to add to each rank that has been used before:

```
=RANK(A1,$A$1:$A$100,1)+COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)-1
```

Which several sites online claim will give me the ranks I am looking for, but I end up with some ranks unused and some duplicate values. The following is a sample of this issue, Column A is raw data, Column B has the above equation in B1 which was dragged down to B100.

```
1   1
2   2
3   4
4   6
5   10
6   11
7   14
8   15
9   18
10  21
10.95210824 23
11.90421647 24
12.85632471 28
13.80843294 29
14.76054118 31
15.71264941 34
16.66475765 37
17.61686588 38
18.56897412 41
19.52108235 42
20.338495   46
21.15590765 48
2   3
4   7
6   12
8   16
10  22
12  25
14  30
16  35
18  39
20  44
21.90421647 49
23.80843294 50
25.71264941 54
27.61686588 56
29.52108235 58
31.42529882 61
33.3295153  64
35.23373177 66
37.13794824 69
39.04216471 71
40.67699    74
42.3118153  76
3   5
6   13
9   19
12  26
15  33
18  40
21  47
24  51
27  55
30  60
32.85632471 63
35.71264941 67
38.56897412 70
41.42529882 75
44.28162353 78
47.13794824 80
49.99427294 82
52.85059765 85
55.70692236 88
58.56324706 89
61.015485   92
63.46772295 94
4   8
8   17
12  27
16  36
20  45
24  52
28  57
32  62
36  68
40  73
43.80843294 77
47.61686588 81
51.42529882 84
55.23373177 87
59.04216471 90
62.85059765 93
66.65903059 95
70.46746353 96
74.27589647 97
78.08432942 98
81.35398001 99
84.62363059 100
5   10
10  22
15  33
20  45
25  53
30  60
35  65
40  73
45  79
50  83
54.76054118 86
59.52108235 91
```

Ranks that don't appear: 9,20,32,43,59,72

Ranks that appear twice: 10,22,33,45,60,73

Does anyone know why this is happening or have a better ranking equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider de-conflicing ties **before** ranking.  In **B1** enter:

```
=A1
```

in **B2** enter:

```
=A2+0.00001*(COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)-1)
```

and copy downwards.  Then in **C1** enter:

```
=RANK(B1,$B$1:$B$100,1)
```

[image]

Note:

Each value in column **B** appears only once.
The ranks in column **C** are consecutive and there are no repeats and no missings.

Comment: This one worked for me! Thank you! Having to make extra columns is kind of gross but functional is functional :D

Comment: @Hoog  I use this technique frequently to "sort-by-formula"

Answer (score 1):

Try using this in column B instead, Paste into `B1`, enter the formula and drag down.

```
=IF(A1=0,"",RANK(A1,IF(A:A>0,A:A,1),0)+COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1)-2)
```

Not quite sure how it works out, but it worked for me on your data set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately that didn't work in my spreadsheet. I don't know a lot of reasons why this would work on one machine and not another, so I updated Office but still no luck :S